# Generate JSON ouput with the echo values

Tags: php, json

I am having a function

```
function currency($from_Currency,$to_Currency,$amount) {
```

which echo the results successfully.

```
echo currency("USD","INR",1.00),"india.png","\n";
echo currency("USD","EUR",1.00),"europe.png","\n";
echo currency("USD","GBP",1.00),"england.png","\n";
echo currency("USD","AED",1.00),"uae.png","\n";
echo currency("USD","CNY",1.00),"china.png","\n";
echo currency("USD","CAD",1.00),"canada.png","\n";
echo currency("USD","PKR",1.00),"pakistan.png","\n";
echo currency("USD","ZAR",1.00),"southafrica.png","\n";
echo currency("USD","CAD",1.00),"canada.png","\n";
echo currency("USD","JPY",1.00),"japan.png","\n";
echo currency("USD","NZD",1.00),"newzealand.png","\n";
echo currency("USD","NPR",1.00),"nepal.png","\n";
```

Since the echo values can only be returned if I pass USD,INR,EUR... values in the function .I have appended the image name also.
I want to generate the JSON ouput with the echo values . Can someone please provide me idea to ac.

The ouput I get from echo value is like this

```
54.42india.png
0.77europe.png
0.65england.png
3.67uae.png
6.17china.png
1.02canada.png
98.48pakistan.png
9.1southafrica.png
1.02canada.png
98.22japan.png
1.18newzealand.png
87.01nepal.png
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by echo values?

Comment: what do you mean output it to json ? you have a format that you know you want and you don't know how to do it ? what is that format ?

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst Please see the main question I have edited. I mean to say at last I echoed the values . I want to show it as in JSON format . How can I achieve that ?

Comment: @Adidi Actually all values are different so I am confused how can I make its output as JSON output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand your question It'll be better to re-factor the code as below.

- Create an array which contains all the data you want.
- Then use [json_enocde](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to encode data - It returns the JSON representation of a value

EG :

```
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

O/P

```
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
```

Then use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to decode the relevant data.

## Note

You don't have to create the JSON object by using echos. It will be a lot easier for you by using above method. Use [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate your JSON object.

Comment: Since the values can aonly be feteched if I pass the values in function . How can make the array ?As far I understand your point is like if I make array $array=array ('INR'=?,'EUR'=?,....); what values I have to be in '?'. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks

Comment: just have an array of arrays; something like: `$result = array( array(currency("USD","INR",1.00), "india.png"), array(currency("USD","EUR",1.00),"europe.png") .... );`

Comment: @Eineki the output is 
[[54.42,"india.png"],[0.77,"europe.png"],[98.22,"japan.png"],[0.65,"england.png"],[3.67,"uae.png"],[6.17,"china.png"],[1.02,"canada.png"],[98.48,"pakistan.png"],[9.1,"southafrica.png"],[1.18,"newzealand.png"]] not JSON. Please help

Comment: @Deonia It is JSON, indeed. what format do you need to put your data? It is not so easy to guess it from your question.

Comment: @Eineki Thanks .. I validated .. its perfect :D

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest way it to create a standard class object and convert that to json.

```
$list = array();

$currency = new stdClass();
$currency->currency = currency("USD","INR",1.00);
$currency->image = "india.png";

$list[] = $currency;


echo json_encode($list);
```

If you only want to output a object

```
echo json_encode($currency);
```

Comment: @Brat what about if I want to show 3 currency . Becaue if I use your mwthod , the JSON is not valid for next 2 currency.

Comment: But I have multiple currency not only INR . How can we handle that . Please help

Comment: It's just an example. The rest is up to you.